# How to repeat a movieclip again before it stops

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, movieclip

I know this question has been asked before but as a noob i did not understand the answer so im hoping someone can explain a little more for me.

I have an arrow animated along a path using a motion tween I want when a button is clicked for an endless stream of arrows to follow the path, this would be easy if you could put more than one object on a motion tween but you cant? Can anyone help with the code id need to make this happen.

Is there a way to repeat the movieclip again before its finished to give this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any code, or example of exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

You can use multiple instances of the same movie clip... So (for the sake of explanation) you could animate your arrow once, make sure it's its own movieClip, put it on the stage, and test your movie...It will loop over and over. You can drag as many instances of this movie on to the stage and they will all play, over and over until it's told to stop.

If you need ALL of the arrows to be one movie clip, as to be one addressable object, you can simply select all of your positioned arrows, and convert those into one movieClip (right click, convert to Symbol)

Of course all of this can be controlled precisely through code, but need to know a bit more about what you're trying to do. hope this helps a little...

Answer (score -1):

The function play() will loop your movie forever, unless you have a stop() function somewhere.

```
yourMovie.play();
```

If you want to "repeat" / "reset" a MovieClip at any time, use gotoAndPlay() :

```
yourMovie.gotoAndPlay(1);
```

If you want to verify if you are at the end of your clip, use the properties currentFrame and totalFrames :

```
if (yourMovie.currentFrame == yourMovie.totalFrames)
{
  // ex. if you want to stop
  yourMovie.stop();
}
```

Ref : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html

Hope that help.  Be more specific, if it doesn't answer your question.